Is this still an uncontrolled command line, which can execute malicious code?
import os

command = "conda run -n python3.5 python generate_handwriting.py -text '{}' -style {} -bias {} -stroke_color '{}' -stroke_width {} -output '{}'".format(text, style, bias, stroke_color, stroke_width, output_filename)


os.system(command)

I get the variables, for example text, directly from the user. I've been notified that this could allow the user to execute malicious code. I have rewritten the code to this:
import subprocess

cmd = ["conda", "run", "-n", "python3.5", "python", "generate_handwriting.py"]
args = ["-text", str(text), "-style", str(style), "-bias", str(bias), "-stroke_color", str(stroke_color), "-stroke_width", str(stroke_width), "-output", output_filename]

process = subprocess.run(cmd + args, check=True)

Is the issue fixed now?
The full code can be found here.

I don't think the change above makes any difference to the possibility of code injection, both variations are functionally the same

To make it safe you would need to validate the values of each var, for example that stroke_color was a hex color string(?) and nothing else. If any of the vars don't have a constrained set of valid values that won't be possible though (e.g. if text var could be "any text" ...that makes securing it difficult)

@Anentropic Not sure if this has been edited in the meantime, but as it stands right now, you're mistaken. subprocess.run restricts execution to a single command and forbids redirects by default. It also allows using a list form, where each list element corresponds to exactly one argument, so the call will most likely just fail because of the malicious input. There are some other potential security issues, however.

Shell Injection
The subprocess.run command, as opposed to os.system, doesn't allow for arbitrary shell execution, like redirections or multiple commands in one string, by default. You'd have to explicitely set shell=True for that.
Also, you're putting the arguments in a list, which is pretty much the Python equivalent of SQL's prepared statements.
Therefore, it is much better to do it like this.
That being said, I'd still advise you to escape user input with shlex.quote, just on general principle. For example, imagine you were to pass a single string command to run, instead of a command list, then a malicious user could pass something like -c "my arbitrary command".
This shouldn't be an issue in your specific case, but better safe than sorry.
Other Issues
If this process is running with higher permissions than the user, you'd need to make sure to close other avenues of attack as well. Some obvious ones would be:

Checking that the user has permissions to edit the output destination.
Restricting write access to generate_handwriting.py.
PATH poisoning, such that the conda executable is provided by the user.

But these are from the top of my head and there might very well be more.
